# R fill list into column based on index

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a number of sets of data of differing length that I am trying to make into an ordered data structure.

At the present time I am trying to inset lists into the regular data structure based on filling by index number.

with the following code:

```
mat <- matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=6)

mat[,1] <- LETTERS[1:5]

vec1 <- c("B","D","E")

vec2 <- c("A","C","E")

m1 <- match(mat[,1],vec1)

m2 <- match(mat[,1],vec2)


x1 <- which(!is.na(m1))

x2 <- which(!is.na(m2))
```

I would like to know how to procede to get:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "A"   NA   "A"   NA   NA   NA

[2,] "B"  "B"   NA    NA   NA   NA

[3,] "C"   NA   "C"   NA   NA   NA  

[4,] "D"  "D"   NA    NA   NA   NA 

[5,] "E"  "E"   "E"   NA   NA   NA
```

Any suggestions or hints please?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mat[match(vec1, mat[,1]), 2] <- vec1 
mat[match(vec2, mat[,1]), 3] <- vec2 
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "A"  NA   "A"  NA   NA   NA  
# [2,] "B"  "B"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
# [3,] "C"  NA   "C"  NA   NA   NA  
# [4,] "D"  "D"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
# [5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  NA   NA   NA
```

Or

```
mat[mat[, 1] %in% vec1, 2] <- vec1 
mat[mat[, 1] %in% vec2, 3] <- vec2
```

Or a more general approach

```
mylist <- list(vec1, vec2)
indx <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(mylist) + 1)[-1], 
        function(x) match(matchlist[[x-1]], mat[, 1])))
indx2 <- rep(seq_len(length(mylist) + 1)[-1], sapply(mylist , length))
mat[cbind(indx, indx2)] <- unlist(mylist)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do if you have more number of columns to match:

```
   mat1 <- mat 
   indx <-  which(outer(mat[,1], c(vec1, vec2), "=="), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]
   indx1 <- rep(1:2, c(length(vec1), length(vec2))) +1

   mat[cbind(indx, indx1)] <- c(vec1,vec2)
   mat
   #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
   #[1,] "A"  NA   "A"  NA   NA   NA  
   #[2,] "B"  "B"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
   #[3,] "C"  NA   "C"  NA   NA   NA  
   #[4,] "D"  "D"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
   #[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  NA   NA   NA
```

Suppose, you need to fill a couple more columns based on multiple vector matching

```
  vec3 <- c("A", "D")
  vec4 <- c("B", "C")
  veclist <- mget(ls(pattern="vec\\d"))

  unlist(veclist, use.names=FALSE)
  #[1] "B" "D" "E" "A" "C" "E" "A" "D" "B" "C"

  indx <-  which(outer(mat[,1], unlist(veclist), "=="), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]

  indx1 <- rep(seq(length(veclist))+1, sapply(veclist, length))
  mat1[cbind(indx, indx1)] <- unlist(veclist)
  mat1
  #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  #[1,] "A"  NA   "A"  "A"  NA   NA  
  #[2,] "B"  "B"  NA   NA   "B"  NA  
  #[3,] "C"  NA   "C"  NA   "C"  NA  
  #[4,] "D"  "D"  NA   "D"  NA   NA  
  #[5,] "E"  "E"  "E"  NA   NA   NA
```